# PowerShell script to check file older than 90 days output

Tags: powershell, file

**So i have a PS script which check files older than 90 days. The problem is the output. I need a output which just says " The folder contains files older than 90 days" . Instead of this the script gives  the mentioned output for every single file like a list. is there way to change it?**

Code :

```
 $a = Get-ChildItem "*insert path*"
    
    foreach($x in $a)
        {
            $y = ((Get-Date) – $x.CreationTime).Days
            if ($y -gt 90 -and $x.PsISContainer -ne $True)
            {
            
            write-host "Files older than 90 days exist"
            }
                 
        }
```

Output i get :
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist
Files older than 90 days exist

Comment: So they always enter a folder path, and then the script should output if that folder has files older than 90 days just once?

Comment: Yes. i resolved using by adding a count variable. Now i am getting different error.

Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:5 char:9
+         $y = ((Get-Date) – $x.CreationTime).Days
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.2#) your loop if the condition is `$true` at least once. In addition, `Get-ChildItem` has a `-File` switch to search only for files, you don't need to check if `.PsISContainer` is `$false`.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "enter path here" -File
$limit = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-90)
foreach($file in $files) {
    if ($file.CreationTime -lt $limit) {
        '{0} contains files older than 90 days' -f $file.Directory
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the solution But i am getting below error
Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:5 char:9
+         $y = ((Get-Date) – $x.CreationTime).Days
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: I dont know that's not the code I posted @DummySrijan

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this.

```
 $Path = "C:\Users\skmohan\Documents\Srija\Js\*"
 $count = 0
foreach($x in $Path)
    {
        $y = ((Get-Date) – $x.CreationTime).Days
        if ($y -gt 90 -and $x.PsISContainer -ne $True)
        {
        $count++
        
        } 

            
    }
    if($count -gt 0)
    {
    write-host "$count Files older than 90 days exist"
    
    }

    else 
    {
    Write-Host "No files older than 90 days"

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting below error Now. when i add this script with another code block
Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:9 char:9
+         $y = ((Get-Date) – $x.CreationTime).Days
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest